# How can one establish a keyboard shortcut for inserting the current date in Gedit?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

I am looking for a way to establish a keyboard-shortcut for inserting the current date when using the text-editor, Gedit.
I know it can be done by selecting "Insert Date and Time" in the "Tools" menu - but this is laborious - a keystroke facility would be magic!

Comment: As you will find in the duplicate question, you can implement that through a bash function. That does not use the plugin: it is not possible - curiously enough - to directly bind a shortcut to the plugin.

Comment: Great!
Yes, this answers very nicely.
Many thanks.